# Zend Server 6 apc not working

Tags: php, apc, zend-server

I have installed Zend Server 6 on Windows 7. Downloaded non thread safe apc dll (php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86.zip) from [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/). When I add apc extension in php.ini zend server is not starting. There were no problems with previous version of Zend Server. What can cause it?

UPDATE: 
There is an error in log file.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class  does not exist' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\GUI\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection.php:172
```

Comment: Anything in your logs?

Comment: @tristan Yes there is an error in php log file. I have updated my question.

Comment: I wonder if you're missing files.  Did you use a tutorial for the install?  If so, please include a link to it.

Comment: I have placed php_apc.dll in ph extensions folder (Zend/ZendServer/lib/phpext) and added `extension=php_apc.dll` to php.ini. It was working with previous version of Zend Server.

Comment: Same problem here, any solution?

Comment: Right now I'm using built in APC which is already included in ZendServer. It is missing some functions (like `apc_exists()`) but at least it's working.